# Do you know what Technology and Platform is powering Android Marketplace?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-play

Does anyone have a good link to know what technologies and platform is being used to power the Android Marketplace?

What would be the best way to create a cost effective "clone" for a smaller audience?

Is it built on top of Google App Engine? Does anyone have an article describing the architecture behind that project?

*I think people are not reading the question correctly... I am looking for an overview to the architectural problem, not just that it's a servlet, or asp page, etc... I am wondering if there is a paper or article on this topic, or Amazon Android store.*

Comment: Honestly, there no reason why he shouldn't be able to ask such a question an be frowned upon. Android was developed with the mind of open source. Meaning that people can utilize the code available to create amazing things or develop their own style of how they would like it to work. People need to lighten up...

Comment: Indeed Android as a client is truly open source, but on the server side, I fail to see any documentation on how to set-up our own instances of an Android Marketplace... witch is pretty much what I am asking, perhaps not in a clear enough way.

Comment: No, it wasn't a clear enough way, apparently... you specifically asked "Is it built on top of Google App Engine"? The answer to that is: no, it is built on GSE. I'm sorry no one can answer what Google has done internally, because that's simply not public knowledge. I'm sorry you feel victimized as a result. FYI: AOSP is open source, but the rest of the "with Google" platform is not - that includes Gmail, Gtalk, YouTube and (surprise!) Market. The reason you won't get any more than what has already been said, is because it's simply not public knowledge. That's not me being rude, it's just fact.

Comment: How is this a different type of question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533948/facebook-architecture and others???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the same infrastructure as other Google service, which is

Distributed Systems Infrastructure:

1. GFS (Google File System),
2. MapReduce,
3. BigTable,
4. Geo-distributed.

Article :

1. [High Scalability Google Architecture](http://highscalability.com/google-architecture) (The detail of what I wrote on top )
2. [Video: Building Large Systems at Google](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-5699448884004201579)
3. [How Google Works](http://www.baselinemag.com/c/a/Infrastructure/How-Google-Works-1/)
4. [Google Lab: MapReduce: Simplified Data Processing on Large Clusters](http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html)

And for your question about "What would be the best way to create a cost effective "clone" for a smaller audience?"

1. **If you want to clone Android MarketPlace:**

   I believe you should ask Google Engineer by yourself. Check their contacts in [Google Developer Advocates](http://code.google.com/team/index.html?product=android)  Please share later. :) I know this could be done since in my country each telco has their own marketplace.
2. **Else If you want to clone the Google Architecture** :

   Google Apps Engine, because it's the Google Architecture in a smaller size. But Google Apps Engine is not really geo-distributed, because last week I just heard from Google Engineer that Google Apps Engine is currently deployed only in America and Europe. ( While other services are distributed all over the world )

Comment: just for curiosity, do you want to clone android market place or just Google Architecture?

Comment: android marketplace similar to what Amazon, Gameloft http://www.gameloft.com/android-hd-games/ and others have done, I think it is the one true advantage over the iPhone model. I would actually love to use the Google Cloud infrastructure, and their model, it would save many months of development.

Answer (score 0):

The same things that Google uses to build their other services.

Comment: This answer is amusing.  Particularly so if you know who hackbod is :)

Comment: It probably is, however it is of no use to me... Would have appreciated some details on how to create a clone of Android Marketplace. I seriously see no point in this anwser.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the response headers, you'll see:

```
$ curl https://market.android.com -v -o /dev/null
...
> GET / HTTP/1.1
...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
< Server: GSE
...
```

Enter that string "GSE" into Google (and for good measure, add "google"), and the first result is for "[OpenGSE](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/01/opengse-released.html)"

Comment: I think people are not reading the question correctly... I am looking for an overview to the architectural problem, not just that it's a servlet, or asp page, etc... I am wondering if there is a paper or article on this topic