# What data structure is used to implement facebook like's post and comments?

Tags: data-structures

This is one of my java interview questions...

I was asked which data structure would you use to implement Facebook post, like and comments?

I would love to hear the view of all the members....

Comment: click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487476/facebook-like-data-structure)

Comment: This article mainly deals with how data is getting stored in database... i am more concerned with how programmatically u can represent data so that it can be more optimized....

Answer (score 0):

This is really more a task for a database (notice how complex the below is, compared to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487476/facebook-like-data-structure/1711796) (because all of the below is taken care of with a proper database with proper indexing)), but...

Note I'm assuming only posts can be liked and comments are for a post.

**Posts:**

Posts can probably be **a Map of post ID to post object**.

If you want to see a list of posts a user made, you'll also need **a Map of user ID to a Set of post IDs**.

**Likes:**

You want to quickly get the number of likes per post and see whether a user liked a post, so **a Map of post ID to a Set of user IDs** of those who like it.

If you also want to quickly see which things a user likes, you'll need a another data structure - **a Map of user ID to a Set of post IDs** liked.

**Comments:**

Comments can probably be **a Map of comment ID to comment object**. The connected post ID will be stored in the comment object.

You want to quickly get the comments per post, so **a Map of post ID to a Set of comment IDs**.

If you also want to quickly see a list of comments made by a user, you'll need a another data structure - **a Map of user ID to a Set of comment IDs**.