# Is there any abstraction layer to work with GFS or HDFS?

Tags: sql, hadoop, nosql, hdfs, gfs

The SQL and NOSQL databases are used by facebook

1.Whether it uses GFS or HDFS or BOTH or some other?

2.What are the different Abstraction application layer available to work on HDFS AND GFS ??

3.I heard about HADOOP , How Map Reduce works ?

kindly narrate the advantages.

And also narrate about the second question deeply.

Comment: GFS and HDFS are damn same. Google open sourced its GFS in the name of  HDFS.  Similar BigTable and Hadoop respectively.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how a specific companies does things, as opposed to a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. This is not a real question.
2. There are really thousands of articles out there.
3. To guide you into the right direction:

Facebook uses a lot of different technologies. SQL and NoSql. It is known that they use a lot Cassandra. Have a look at this [video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Scale-at-Facebook) from the director of engineering from Facebook.

Here are also some more links of the Facebook architecture:
[Facebook Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533948/facebook-architecture)

Comment: Yeah !!Second point you said is perfectly correct :) anyhow thanks for sharing your view :)